# How to switch form from readonly True to False in view?

Tags: django

I have a form for an account and I wish to make it ReadOnly and Updatable.

How should I handle the switch from readonly True to False?

I know about this:

```
self.fields['fieldname'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control', 'readonly': True})
```

I hope that there is a way to remove readonly on view so that I won't need to create a separate form.

Or you can also suggest other solution for my concern.
Or should I create a separate Form for readonly?

Comment: why don't use the html tag `readonly`. Use that tag for the fields which you want to be readonly

Comment: Yes I know about the readonly. But on my template. I want to load it as readonly as default. Then with a push of a button, can be updated

Comment: Give a `name` for that tag too and read that in the views. Even if it is readonly, you will be able to read that field in `views.py`

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG How should I do this? can you provide a sample line?

Answer (score 2):

In your html file, say you this form

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'some_view' %}">
   <input type="text" value="something" name="field1" readonly>
   <input type="text" value="something1" name="field2" >
   <input type="text" value="something2" name="field3">
   <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Now in your views.py, you can read all the three variables using the name of the tag
`views.py`

```
def func(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        field1 = request.POST['field1']
        field2 = request.POST['field2']
        field3 = request.POST['field3']
        #Do Db update or any other
        return HttpResponse('success')
```

You can do in the above way

Comment: But I load my forms like this:

`{{ form.someform }}`

Comment: There won't be any problem even if you load the form from `forms.py`. Just make sure you write the name in the attributes of the filed in `forms.py`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the idea. I also used jquery to generate readonly instead of adding new form with readonly attr.